# Need help finding a way to set up a booking system for expressionengine

Tags: cartthrob

I'm looking for a good solution for setting up a reservation/booking system as part of an ExpressionEngine website I am estimating for a client. I am ideally looking for something that will integrate with Cartthrob for payment for reservations. If anyone has a suggestion I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Brian Rivet
brian@odysseydesignstudio.com

Comment: Hi Brian, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Paul. No I didn't but it ended up not being an issue. That being said I am always on the lookout for stuff like this just in case it comes up again.

Answer (score 1):

There is always moreEvents ( http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/moreevents ) that allows you to sell event registrations with CartThrob.